# How can I force Google Chrome to ignore built-in keystrokes and pass them to jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, hotkeys

I'm developing commerce system. I want the system to be as lightweight as possible. I develop it on linux, of course. I want to achieve this:

I want to develop something like a desktop environment, just in HTML5/CSS3/jQuery.
I'm in a early phase of development, I'm testing several possibilities.
Now I know, I can boot right to google chrome in kiosk mode.
I can therefore develop anything I want, the only limitation is the screen resolution.
I've been testing [jQuery Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys). Now I know I can handle pretty much any hotkey, except for those like Alt-F4, Ctrl-W, and so on. Is it possible to force these hotkeys to be ignored by chrome and passed to script? Thanks for any help

Comment: How is it lightweight if it runs in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Script can never override browser behavior.  It is not possible to catch browser-defined keyboard shortcuts.

If your application is to be used on systems you have control over (in other words, it's an internal app), you could write a wrapper for the WebKit engine that does not have its own keyboard shortcuts, or perhaps use [an existing one](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Applications%20using%20WebKit#KioskSoftware).